# Pass data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an app, when the user clicks on the login button, the user's information is sent to the profile page after verifying the identity.
Well, no problem so far
The problem is when I use this profile class in several other places and I have to pass parameters to those classes as well.
What is the solution?
Thankful

Answer (score 1):

[InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) could be used for this. Or you could use a more advanced state management solution like [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)

Answer (score -1):

Here are 2 ways to accomplish what you're looking for:

1. Create a `profile.dart` file, with global variables to store all the information you need. Then for any other page that needs this info, you can use `import "profile.dart"`.
2. Store all your profile information in a single `class`. That way, you only need to pass 1 extra parameter when the profile info is needed.